# Dask.distributed scheduling between workers on various hosts

Tags: python, dask, hpc, dask-distributed

> Each worker contains a ThreadPool that it uses to evaluate tasks as
> requested by the scheduler. It stores the results of these tasks
> locally and serves them to other workers or clients on demand. If the
> worker is asked to evaluate a task for which it does not have all of
> the necessary data then it will reach out to its peer workers to
> gather the necessary dependencies.

-- from https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html

My question is about how smart is the process of allocating tasks and passing results:

- Does the data scheduler only consider data locality in terms of workers, or it also considers if workers are on the same physical host?
- When passing results from one task to another in the same worker (say a `numpy` array), does it copy data, makes it immutable or allows for copy on write?

Comment: When using a cluster of computers it does not make sense to have multiple workers on the same host. They just would need to share the available ressources. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @JulianWgs, we're using worker and the process terms to some extent interchangeably here. In Python it does make sense to start multiple processes (or workers) on the same host, as parallelization is usually faster for processes than threads (due to GIL).